# PHP - DB connection that works on localhost and webserver

Tags: php, database, connection, webserver, localhost

I'd like to have a database connection php file that would work with both localhost and in the webserver. The idea is to use some constants if I'm on localhost and other if I'm on the webserver.

---

Edit: The solution of the question was to know weather I'm on localhost or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost") {
    mysql_connect($host_local, ...);
} else {
    mysql_connect($host_web, ...);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$local = array('localhost', '127.0.0.1');

if(in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $local)).     
{
$pdo = new      PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');
}
else
{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=example.com;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');
}
```

You should use PDO. This will check for localhost and 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2):

What you really need to do is make configuration files that are versioned per environment. You'll have a local/dev config file with your database connection information and then another config file for production or staging.

You simply point your PHP application at the appropriate config file and then the application will communicate with the right database machine.

It's a bad idea to try to make the application point to multiple environments. It will be really confusing quickly.